# How do I get date object of start date and end date in default material date picker in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, material-components-android

I am getting "15 Jan - 31 Jan" string when I select this range. But I want date object of start and end date instead of that string.

[image: Screenshot of circled date range picker with a red pen]

This is how I show the date picker:

```kt
private fun setupRangePickerDialog() {
        val builder: MaterialDatePicker.Builder<*> = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
        val constraintsBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        try {
            builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())
            val picker: MaterialDatePicker<*> = builder.build()
            getDateRange(picker)
            picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {

        }
    }
```

Here in `addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` I get that string,

```kt
private fun getDateRange(materialCalendarPicker: MaterialDatePicker<out Any>) {
        materialCalendarPicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(
            { selection: Any? ->
                Log.e("DateRangeText",materialCalendarPicker.headerText)
//here i want start and end date
            })
        materialCalendarPicker.addOnNegativeButtonClickListener(
            { dialog: View? ->
            }
        )
        materialCalendarPicker.addOnCancelListener(
            { dialog: DialogInterface? ->
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: In your listener you can use something like: `Pair<Long,Long> selection)`. Check the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931051/materialdatepicker-get-selected-dates/58931200#58931200).

Comment: Thanks, @GabrieleMariotti for the reply.  But if I do like picker.headerText then I am getting "7 Jan – 23 Jan" like this. And if I do picker.selection.toString then I am getting Pair{1578355200000 1579737600000} like this.

Comment: And it is correct. `1578355200000` is just the long value of 7 Jan.

Comment: Thank you so much @GabrieleMariotti. And are there any things to do for smooth run. Because when I am scroll months vertically then it doesn't seem smooth scrolling.

Comment: You can only try to use the latest version or open an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).